# Doctrine2 FindOneBy and SQL Injection

Tags: doctrine-orm

Is this code (in Doctrine2) secured against SQL injection? Or should be $_GET['value']
sanitized?

```
$ret = $entityManager->getRepository('SomeEntity')->findOneBy(array('ID' => $_GET['value']));
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is secured from SQL-injection. You can find look at the source to find this out, the relevant code is in the [`Doctrine\ORM\Persisters`](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/tree/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters)-namespace, as well as [`Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository`](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php) and [`Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork`](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php).

Your criteria is converted into placeholders, which is also the recommended way of writing your own queries to protect against SQL-injection.